# Could someone check my work for this vector/parametric problem?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vectors, parametric

The motion of  a particle is described by the set of parametric equations $x=\frac{t}{5}+1$, $y=2t-e^{\frac{t}{2}}+1$, for $0\le t\le 5$

a) Find the coordinates of the absolute maximum and minimum. Justify your answer
$\frac{dy}{dt}=2-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{t}{2}}=0$

$t=2.77259$

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
t & x(t) & y(t)\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
2.77259 & 1.55452 & 2.54518\\ \hline
5 & 2 & -1.18249\\ \hline
\end{array}$

Answer: The absolute max is 2.545 and occurs at t=2.773, and the absolute min is -1.182 and occurs at t=5 by EVT.

b) Find the x-intercept of the line tangent to the graph at t=2.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{5}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ when t=2 is 3.204245

x(2)=1.4; y(2)=2.282

y-2.282 = 3.204(x-1.4)

Answer: The x-intercept of the line tangent to the graph at t=2 is 1.4.

c) Find the length of the graph from t=0 to t=5

$\int _0^5\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\left(2-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{t}{2}}\right)^2dt}=6.426\:$

Comment: What does the $\max,\min$ of a particle mean? It is hard to check your work if you don't show it.

Comment: For (b), I think you're misunderstanding. Express the tangent equation you found in terms of $x$ as a function of $y$, then set $y=0$ to find the x-intercept.

Comment: So for b, I would set y=3.204(x-1.4)+2.282 to 0?

Comment: Yes you wrote the same thing. That is correct. Also in a) max does not occur at $t = 5$. You have a typo.

Comment: @JulesL. yes, and solve for $x$.